# SQL Server 2019 - For XML Path - non ascii characters encoding

Tags: sql-server, non-ascii-characters, for-xml-path

I need to build a "complex" `xml` to generate AWB labels

addresses can contains "forbidden"  xml characters &,",<,> and also ',ä,å and so on

therefore, trying to solve the problem I created a simple function that replace such characters:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[encodeXML](@t nvarchar(512))
returns nvarchar(512)
as
begin
  --if @t is not null and @t <>''
    return trim(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t,'&','&amp;'),'"','&quot;'),'<','&lt;'),'>','&gt;'),'''','&apos;'))
end
```

This function encodes "`Quartu Sant'Elena`" into "`Quartu Sant&apos;Elena`"

But details for each shipment are encapsulated into xml node via `for xml path ('Parcel'), type`

and "`Quartu Sant&apos;Elena`" becomes "`Quartu Sant&amp;apos;Elena`" that is not accepted.

how can I fix it?

Pls note that all shipments are further incapsulated in for xml path ('Info') container
therefore the solution shall solve both for xml functions

Comment: `FOR XML` is *supposed* to encode them, you don't need to do your own encoding. It's incorrect in XML to have these characters unencoded. If you always use `,TYPE` then you won;t get double-encoding when nesting `FOR XML`

Comment: @MitchWheat some of those characters are quite common in parts of the world, e.g.: `Frogmorton & Sons, Solictors` and quotes in house names `Mr & Mrs J. Smith\n"Cute Cottage"\n123 Some Road\nLittle Suburb...`

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for replying.. I remember that I added such function because of some encoding error but do not remember which one.. will try remove the function and see if some error arises..